# Create .apk file for Xamarin Android project with custom build configuration

Tags: android, xamarin, msbuild, apk

Let's say I have a solution for a Xamarin Android project named X.Droid containing following projects:

```
    - Core.PCL 
        build configurations: Debug, Release, XRelease
    - AndroidLibrary (references Core.PCL )
        build configurations: Debug, Release
    - X.PCL (references Core.PCL )
        build configurations: Debug, Release
    - X.Droid (references X.PCL and AndroidLibrary)
        build configurations: Debug, Release, Test, Prod
```

Platform='AnyCPU' if set for each of these configurations (without space, not 'Any CPU')

I have set up a solution configuration X.Test to have these projects configurations:

```
    - XRelease for Core.PCL (Build)
    - Release for AndroidLibrary (Build)
    - Release for X.PCL (Build)
    - Test for X.Droid (Build, Deploy)
```

Again Platform='AnyCPU' (without space)

This configuration is being built fine when I use either Visual Studio 2015 or msbuild directly like this:

```
    MSBuild.exe X.sln /p:Configuration=X.Test;Platform=AnyCPU
```

After building the output folder for X.Droid project (bin\Test) contains only *.dll, *.mdb, *.pdb and *.xml files.

Now I'd like to have an .apk file generated from this output. According to [documenetation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/under_the_hood/build_process/) target 'SignAndroidPackage' "Creates and signs the package (.apk)" But when I run

```
    MSBuild.exe X.Droid.csproj /p:Configuration=Test /t:SignAndroidPackage
```

I receive the following output:

> Project "C:...\X.Droid.csproj" on node 1 (SignAndroidPackage
>   target(s)).
>
> Properties\AndroidManifest.xml : warning XA0101: @(Content) build
>   action is not supported [C:...\X.Droid.csproj]
>
> Project "C:...\X.Droid.csproj" (1) is building
>   "C:...\Core.PCL.csproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(723,5):
>   error : The OutputPath property is not set for project
>   'Core.PCL.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified
>   a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project. 
>   Configuration='Test'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing this
>   message because you are trying to build a project without a solution
>   file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that
>   doesn't exist for this project. [C:...\Core.PCL.csproj]
>
> Done Building Project "C:...\Core.PCL.csproj" (default targets) --
>   FAILED.
>
> Project "C:...\X.Droid.csproj" (1) is building "C:...\X.PCL.csproj"
>   (4) on node 1 (default targets).
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(723,5):
>   error : The OutputPath property is not set for project 'X.PCL.csproj'.
>   Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination
>   of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Test' 
>   Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing this message because you are
>   trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified
>   a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this
>   project. [C:...\X.PCL.csproj]
>
> Done Building Project "C:...\X.PCL.csproj" (default targets) --
>   FAILED.
>
> Project "C:...\X.Droid.csproj" (1) is building
>   "C:...\AndroidLibrary.csproj" (5) on node 1 (default targets).
>
> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(723,5):
>   error : The OutputPath property is not set for project
>   'AndroidLibrary.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have
>   specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this
>   project.  Configuration='Test'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing
>   this message because you are trying to build a project without a
>   solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or
>   Platform that doesn't exist for this project.
>   [C:...\AndroidLibrary.csproj]
>
> Done Building Project "C:...\AndroidLibrary.csproj" (default targets)
>   -- FAILED.
>
> Done Building Project "C:...\X.Droid.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage
>   target(s)) -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.
>
> "C:...\X.Droid.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target) (1) ->
>   (_CheckForContent target) ->    Properties\AndroidManifest.xml :
>   warning XA0101: @(Content) build action is not supported
>   [C:...\X.Droid.csproj]
>
> "C:...\X.Droid.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target) (1) ->
>   "C:...\Core.PCL.csproj" (default target) (2) ->
>   (_CheckForInvalidConfigurationAndPlatform target) ->    C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(723,5):
>   error : The OutputPath property is not set for project
>   'Core.PCL.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have specified
>   a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this project. 
>   Configuration='Test'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing this
>   message because you are trying to build a project without a solution
>   file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or Platform that
>   doesn't exist for this project. [C:...\Core.PCL.csproj]
>
> "C:...\X.Droid.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target) (1) ->
>   "C:...\X.PCL.csproj" (default target) (4) ->   C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(723,5):
>   error : The OutputPath property is not set for project 'X.PCL.csproj'.
>   Please check to make sure that you have specified a valid combination
>   of Configuration and Platform for this project.  Configuration='Test' 
>   Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing this message because you are
>   trying to build a project without a solution file, and have specified
>   a non-default Configuration or Platform that doesn't exist for this
>   project. [C:...\X.PCL.csproj]
>
> "C:...\X.Droid.csproj" (SignAndroidPackage target) (1) ->
>   "C:...\AndroidLibrary.csproj" (default target) (5) ->   C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(723,5):
>   error : The OutputPath property is not set for project
>   'AndroidLibrary.csproj'.  Please check to make sure that you have
>   specified a valid combination of Configuration and Platform for this
>   project.  Configuration='Test'  Platform='AnyCPU'.  You may be seeing
>   this message because you are trying to build a project without a
>   solution file, and have specified a non-default Configuration or
>   Platform that doesn't exist for this project.
>   [C:\U...\AndroidLibrary.csproj]
>
> ```
> 1 Warning(s)
> 4 Error(s)
> ```
>
> Time Elapsed 00:00:00.83

This output means target 'SignAndroidPackage' actually builds the Android project againg and tries to build each project it depends on with the same build configuration. Which obviously cannot be found in my case.

I understand that one way of solving my problem is to declare 'Test' configuration for each project which X.Droid depends on. But I'd like to find a better solution.

Is there any way I can make 'SignAndroidPackage' to use output which was previously generated with building the entrire X.sln? Or to explicitly tell it configurations names for all participating projects? Or can I tell it the solution file so it will look for them there?

Or is there another target for my purposes?

Comment: Have you have found a solution for this?